# PostgreSQL lock issue on update

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock

I have some performance issue with postgreSQL, and if I query locks with :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_locks pl LEFT JOIN pg_stat_activity psa
ON pl.pid = psa.pid WHERE virtualtransaction='13/309458';
```

I got this:

```
locktype    database  relation  page  tuple virtualxid  transactionid classido  objid objsubid  virtualtransaction  pid mode  granted fastpath  datid datname pid usesysid  usename application_name  client_addr client_hostname client_port backend_start xact_start  query_start state_change  wait_event_type wait_event  state backend_xid backend_xmin  query
transactionid  5986031  13/309458   12718   ExclusiveLock   true    false   16404   peter   12718   16403   peter       35.195.100.216      42828   2018-04-13 07:07:29.948748  2018-04-13 07:08:55.717530  2018-04-13 07:08:55.923704  2018-04-13 07:08:55.923705  Lock    transactionid   active  5986031 5953002 update "users_rooms" set "lastContact" = $1 where "roomId" = $2 and "active" = $3
transactionid  5986018  13/309458   12718   ShareLock   false   false   16404   peter   12718   16403   peter       35.195.100.216      42828   2018-04-13 07:07:29.948748  2018-04-13 07:08:55.717530  2018-04-13 07:08:55.923704  2018-04-13 07:08:55.923705  Lock    transactionid   active  5986031 5953002 update "users_rooms" set "lastContact" = $1 where "roomId" = $2 and "active" = $3
```

I don't know how to read that, but if I try I understand that I have the same update doing 2 times, one inside my transaction and one outside it. This means that they block each others? 
Do you understand the same thing?

If I try to query he active locks, I got very old one, is it normal?
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Maybe try to use (based on your PG version) one of queries from this article - http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/locks-on-objects-with-relationships/ - to see more about locks and if you find something interesting please add it to your description.

Comment: Also, you could set `log_lock_waits` to `on` in `postgresql.conf` (and reload) to get useful information about the lock in the log.